# define preposition in after students and there is need of preposition after again or not

Tags: prepositions

> Many educators believe that a school is supposed to teach students **in** subjects that they will most probably not encounter **again** post-graduation, so that teachers can develop open-minded and well-informed individuals.

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL! What exactly is your question?

Comment: teach subjects to students that they etc. = teach students in subjects that they//same thing, basically.